# name, *line = input().split() in here can i use *line as a list?

Tags: python-3.x

I was doing a question on python and i got "name, *line = input().split() " this line in the code section. Then i searched and found that this line grabs the rest of the input as a list. Now, i want to use ***line** as a list for my furthur code. I have two question here.

1. Is *line actual a list?
2. How Can i use it as a list for furthur calculation?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    student_marks = {}
    for _ in range(n):
        name, *line = input().split()
        scores = list(map(float, line))
        student_marks[name] = scores
    query_name = input()
```

Comment: As you can see further in the code, it is simply used as `line`... And yes it's just a list. This can be verified by doing `type(line)`. Play around with it in a shell. You will learn much more than running here to ask. Print `line`, print its type, play with different values

Answer (score 0):

Annotated code:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input('Enter number of students: '))
    student_marks = {}
    for _ in range(n):  # _ character ignores the value returned by the generator
        # split on whitespace, first argument goes to name, remaining go to line
        name, *line = input('Enter record(name mrks1 mrks2 ...): ').split()
        # line is indeed a list
        print(type(line))
        # parse the list "line" containing strings into floats/real numbers
        scores = list(map(float, line))
        # add it to the student dictionary, with value in "name" as the key
        student_marks[name] = scores
    query_name = input()
```